# How to capture the address an application contacts?

Tags: networking, monitoring

An application contacts an Internet host on each start of it. It seems to take just an instant. I don't know if it is HTTP, plain TCP or UDP or what is used but tend to suppose HTTP. What tool can I use to track this connection?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at  [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Answer (score 1):

#### Watch all network traffic

In a terminal, as root, run

```
tcpdump
```

and watch the packets fly. If you have other network activity, filter that out. For example, to show everything except incoming and outgoing SSH traffic:

```
tcpdump not port 22
```

#### Watch what the application is doing

Run `strace -o myapp.strace myapp`. This writes a log of every system call that the application performs to `myapp.strace`. Look for lines that begin with `connect(`; these are the application opening a TCP or UDP connection. The target IP address and port are on that line. The protocol is determined by the previous `socket` call which comes before and is usually very close. Traffic to port 53 is DNS traffic.